# How to set raw post content while testing restfull controller in zf2?

Tags: php, unit-testing, zend-framework2, phpunit

I've got a test method like this:

```
public function testTaskPut()
{
    $this->dispatch('/task/67', 'put');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    $this->assertModuleName('Task');
    $this->assertControllerName('Task\Controller\Task');
    $this->assertControllerClass('TaskController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('task');
}
```

And now I want to set raw post content:

```
{"content":"example content"}
```

How to do it?

I can do sth like:

```
$request = new Request();
$request->setContent(json_encode(array(
   'content' => 'example content'
)));
```

but how to use `$request` in dispatch()...

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested this, but the ZF test controller class has a request object already which is used for dispatching, so you should be able to do:

```
public function testTaskPut()
{
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $request->setContent(json_encode(array(
       'content' => 'example content'
    )));

    $this->dispatch('/task/67', 'put');
    $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
    $this->assertModuleName('Task');
    $this->assertControllerName('Task\Controller\Task');
    $this->assertControllerClass('TaskController');
    $this->assertMatchedRouteName('task');
}
```

then when you call `dispatch()`, your data should be used.

Comment: Unfortunatelly, my data is not used by `dispatch()`... :(